# openSUSE service MySQL stop is not working

Tags: linux, mysql, opensuse-11.4

I am not sure what I need to do, if anything. Using CentOS, when I run service `mysql stop`, it stops MySQL.

On openSUSE studio, when I run the same command, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

One solution to your problem is to setup mysql as a service. In the mysql installation tarball, there should be a script called `mysql-server` (or something similar). Copy that to `/etc/init.d` and name it `mysql` (you may need to edit it, so that the mysql user is the same as the one you setup on your system and that the path to mysql is the same as the one on your system). After that run the following commands:

```
# chkconfig --add mysql
# chkconfig mysql on
```

You'll then be able to manage mysql using the `service` command e.g.

```
service mysql start
service mysql stop
service mysql status
```

Hope this helps!